# Improving a menu

Tags: bash, menu

I wrote a menu in bash to access for network equipments but now there are a lot of them for showing in one screen to permit selecting one without scroll up or down. I need improving it, attached my actual menu. (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33222611/menu.txt)

The option that I´ve been thinking is to have two file:

1. The list of each equipment. Inside this file put the headers and a ID to discriminate if equipment used ssh or telnet
2. The code to do all the work. Allowing enter into two modes: one where each equipment of list would be printed with a number to allow select any and the other mode that allows entering a search mode

I need your help to make it happen but I accept other suggestions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If this is working code that you want improved this is a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com than here. You may also want to look into the `select` built-in as it was designed for menu systems (though it may not do what you want (and won't page automatically).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have bash version 4, this is a good case for an associative array:

```
declare -A cmd=(
    [ESP_R7609S_MTSO]=ssh
    [ESP_R7609_RIGUERO]=ssh
    [ESP_R7609_SUBASTA]=telnet
    [ESP_R7606_BOLONIA]=ssh
    [ESP_R7609_LINDAVISTA]=ssh
    # etc etc
)

while :; do
    read -p "Enter a hostname: " hostname
    if [[ ${cmd[$hostname]} ]]; then
        "${cmd[$hostname]}" "$hostname"
        break
    else
        echo "unknown hostname. The known hosts are:"
        printf "%s\n" "${!cmd[@]}" | sort | paste - - - - - | column -t | less -E
    fi
done
```

---

Old bash: use "parallel" indexed arrays

```
typeset -a hosts cmds
typeset -i i=0
hosts[i]=ESP_R7609S_MTSO;      cmds[i]=ssh; i=i+1
hosts[i]=ESP_R7609_RIGUERO;    cmds[i]=ssh; i=i+1
hosts[i]=ESP_R7609_SUBASTA;    cmds[i]=telnet; i=i+1
hosts[i]=ESP_R7606_BOLONIA;    cmds[i]=ssh; i=i+1
hosts[i]=ESP_R7609_LINDAVISTA; cmds[i]=ssh; i=i+1
# ...

while :; do
    read -p "Enter a hostname: " hostname
    i=0
    while [[ $i -lt ${#hosts[@]} ]]; do
        if [[ $hostname == ${hosts[i]} ]]; then
            "${cmds[i]}" "$hostname"
            break 2
        fi
        i=i+1
    done 

    echo "unknown hostname. The known hosts are:"
    printf "%s\n" "${hosts[@]}" | sort | pr -t -w $(tput cols) -4 | less -E
done
```

The `typeset -i i` sets the variable `i` with the "integer" attribute, so we can do "bare" arithmetic like `i=i+1`

Comment: bash-2.05$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 2.05.0(1)-release (sparc-sun-solaris2.9)
Copyright 2000 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: bash-2.05$ ./menutest
./menutest[2]: syntax error at line 3 : `(' unexpected

Comment: That is a meaningless error message. what code are you running that produced that?

Comment: my bad, I was testing on the wrong box. ksh88 does not have associative arrays. Updated answer with a bash v2 solution.

Comment: bash-2.05$ ./menutest2
  Enter a hostname: ESP_R7606_BOLONIA
  ./menutest2: : command not found
  bash-2.05$ ./menutest2
  Enter a hostname: ESP_R7609_RIGUERO
  ./menutest2: : command not found

Comment: Found the bug in my code: bad=`"${cmd[i]}"`, good=`"${cmds[i]}"` -- see [the edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29985868/revisions)